# Retrieve the HTML 5 tooltip validation message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, validation, tooltip

I've got a form in my ASP.NET MVC project.

I remember at the begining that my form used to display validation message in a nice tooltip next to the concerned field. And I think it's the default behavior.

But now, for an unknown reason, My HTML5 validation messages are displaying at the bottom of the field, not in a tooltip, written in bold black..

I don't remember what I modified...

Any idea?

**Edit:**

My code in view

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Titre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required" })
            <div class="col-md-5">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Titre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" } })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Titre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

And

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Comment: you should rather post some code and not an image

Comment: You seem to be trying to mix HTML5 validation (`required = "required"`) and MVC's unobtrusive validation which don't play well together (in fact you form element should have the `novalidate` attribute to prevent HTML5 validation)

Comment: MVC's unobtrusive validation prevents HTML5 validation! I'm disappointed.